# Conditionally call a promise (or not), but return either result to another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

having trouble trying to write the following code in a way that doesn't involve nested promises.

```
function trickyFunction(queryOptions, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (data) {
      resolve(data);
    } else {
      // ... a bunch of conditions to check and/or modify queryOptions. These checks and mods
      // are vital but only required if data is not passed in. ...
      if (anErrorHappensHere) {
        reject('Oh no, an error happened');
      }

      somePromise(queryOptions).then((result) => {
        resolve(result);
      });
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    criticalOperation1(result);
    // the code here is long and shouldn't be duplicated
  });
}
```

I really don't like the .then() chain after `somePromise` since it's inside the `new Promise`, but I really don't see a way around it. If I take the conditional out of a promise, then I'd have to duplicate the criticalOperation1 code, which isn't an option here. The conditional checks in the `else` block should only happen if `data` is not passed in. Making other functions is not permitted in my case, and using async/await is also not permitted in my case.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've worked with Promises for a bit but this one is stumping me.

Comment: You should learn new syntax for promise async/await.

Comment: @AshokPatidar Please read my question, I mention that it's not permitted in my case

Answer (score 1):

I would just avoid using the `new Promise` syntax in this case and just start the promise chain early

```
function trickyFunction(queryOptions, data) {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then( () => {
      if (data) {
        return Promise.resolve(data);
      } else {
        // ... a bunch of conditions to check and/or modify queryOptions. These checks and mods
        // are vital but only required if data is not passed in. ...
        if (anErrorHappensHere) {
          // Could also just throw here
          return Promise.reject('Oh no, an error happened');
        }

        return somePromise(queryOptions);
      }
    })
   .then((result) => {
      criticalOperation1(result);
      // the code here is long and shouldn't be duplicated
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to do `return Promise.resolve(data);` inside a `.then()` handler.  You can just do `return data;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function trickyFunction(queryOptions, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (anErrorHappensHere) {
        reject('Oh no, an error happened');
    }
    resolve({data, queryOptions});
    }).then((obj) => {
        if(obj.data){
        return Promise.resolve(obj.data);
        } else {
        return somePromise(obj.queryOptions)
       }
    }).then((result) => criticalOperation1(result));
    .catch((err)=> console.log(err));
}
```